# HTML5 data-attributes in iframe element

Tags: html, iframe, custom-data-attribute

Can custom data-attributes set on an iframe be accessed by the iframe's content?

Example:

```
<iframe src="foo.html" data-something="123"></iframe>
```

Is there a  way to access data-something's value form the iframe's document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, use the [`frameElement` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frameElement).

```
window.frameElement.getAttribute('data-something');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ehj2Q/

Of course this does not work at all if the iframe's content are from a different [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: This is great, but yeah, not the same domain. I guess the iframe's document can't read it's parent tag's attributes at all then.

Comment: That's right. The only thing that both can access is the `src`, which is reflected in the frame content's `location`. So the parent frame can send data using the hash `foo.html#something=123`, like [Closure does](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_net_crossdomainrpc.js.source.html). For modern browsers, there's [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). But again, this is only possible if the parent frame opts in.